# How do I take my Tor node offline permanently?

Tags: relays, exit-relays, network-health

I run a Tor node on a virtual private server, and for various mundane reasons I do not want to continue operating this particular VPS. In other words, I will be removing a Tor node from the network. Are there any steps I should take in advance of shutting down this node for the last time? E.g. any way to advertise to the network that the node will no longer be available? (If there would even be a point to that)

The server in question is not an exit relay at this time, but in general, I'm interested in knowing the answer for both exit and non-exit relays, if there is any difference.

Comment: And yes, I do plan to start up another node to replace this one when circumstances allow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything special that needs to be done, just halt the daemon.  Specifically there's no mechanism for publishing to the Dir Auths that a node will go down permanently.